# What is the name of this strange JSON like format

Tags: ios, format, in-app-purchase

I have found JSON-like format while working on Apple's in-app-purchase API. Apple's in-app subscription returns base64 encoded receipt, and when I am decoding it, it looks like a strange JSON-like formatted string. The part of it looks like this:

```
{
    "purchase_info" = "123";
    "subscription_id" = "7F12371239123";
}
```

Does anybody knows the name of this format?

Comment: That's not JSON, nor it's JS.

Comment: @Tushar yeah I know it's not a JSON nor JS, but it looks a like

Comment: Clarify the context in which you came across this piece of… something.

Comment: @deceze I have already mentioned about Apple's in app purchase

Comment: Can you clarify *even more*…? Link to the page where you saw this for instance?

Comment: This seems to be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list

Comment: @deceze edited, put some context

Comment: Edit your question to show how you are producing the output shown.   Th format of the receipt is documented https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH105-SW1

Comment: It probably doesn't have a name. It looks to me like the output from NSLog or print of a dictionary. That is why I asked where you got that output from.

Comment: Thank you for your time @Paulw11

Answer (score 3):

The format looks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list,
which was used by Apple In the macOS, iOS, NeXTSTEP, and GNUstep programming frameworks.